# How to plot several y values at the same x value coming from different txt files in python

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, graph

I have many .txt files containing several time measurement values (exp. power, temperature, current, force values over times). I need to draw plot (exp.: time-power) in the same plot extracting from 20 txt files, but all of them in the same graph. How can I do it using pandas and Matplot?
How can I plot data coming from different .csv/.txt files that have similar x values (time) but different Y values, with (x-y1) in one graph, then (x-y2) in other graphs?

Comment: You can start with [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and put all the dataframes in a list. Then  loop and plot the desired column from each.

Comment: Then, you could read the [pandas visualization chapter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html) - it uses matplotlib for its plotting. If you have achieved to include all txt files as columns of your pandas df, it will be easy to achieve your goal. Alternatively, read the [matplotlib tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/index.html) which cover your questions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a few rows from your text file (as text, not an image) and explain which parts you are trying to plot from it.